# How to get GPS coordinate from a satellite phone with Raspberry Pi

Tags: wifi, pi-zero, gps

I noticed that when connecting my laptop to the Iridium Satphone, location services picks up the sat phone's GPS location. I was wondering how to replicate this on a Pi, with Python.

My goal is to get the GPS location from the Iridium Sat phone, which seems to automatically broadcast to any connected device with a desktop client with location services feedback, and somehow print into a python script.

Ideally, I would not have to add a second GSP querying piece of hardware, and rely on the one I currently have(the Iridium GO). I am new to Raspberry Pi, I'm currently running the latest Raspbian on a Raspberry Pi 3B+.

Cheers :)

Comment: And what is your question? How to get GPS location on raspi from phone?

Comment: How to get GPS from the WIFI network, with the Pi, in Python. Some kind of way to query the network's location services.

Comment: I believe your task #1 is to understand how to get GPS data out of an Iridium phone. I suspect this is not related to the RPi in particular.

Comment: Connecting an OSX or Windows machine will grant them location services automatically, I shared it here as the Raspberry Pi does not.